# how to search records from mongodb using lucene in java

Tags: java, mongodb, lucene

I have store some records in mongodb database.Now i want to search those records using lucene in java.please suggest me how to do this task.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean using Solr..??

Comment: @user2522836 : view my posted links that are in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you going to asking questions please visit google.
I think it may be helpful to you.
[jayway](http://www.jayway.com/2010/11/14/full-text-search-with-mongodb-and-lucene-analyzers/)

Comment: how to implement Solr

Comment: http://blogs.atlassian.com/rebelutionary/downloads/tssjs2007-lucene-generic-data-indexing.pdf OR
http://derickrethans.nl/mongodb-and-solr.html